# Get an url pk in a generic RESTful view?

Tags: django, rest, generics

I'm trying to manage my REST API like that :

```
http://xxx/users/userid[0-9]+/projects/projectid[0-9]+/tasks/taskid[0-9]+/
```

So I can access the JSON easily in my website. But, the thing is, I defined my view classes using the REST framework generic views. For example, here is my UserDetail view :

```
class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

But of course I don't want all my users to be displayed, I just want my user with the ID userid to be displayed. I don't really know how to do it, I tried

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(id=userid)
```

but of course userid is not defined... Any help please ?

Edit : just to clarify, here is the url that leads to this view :

```
url(r'^users/(?P<pku>[0-9]+)/$', views.UserDetail.as_view(
                   ), name='user-detail'),
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? Also, should it not be `id=pku` because that is the variable name you are using in the url ?

Comment: Do you use django.contrib.auth to define user?

Comment: @karthikr yup sorry I failed, I use pku both in the url and in the queryset.

Comment: @Burton449 no I don't, where should I use user ?

Comment: @Burton449 means are you using a custom User object or inbuilt django user model ? Which version of django are you on ? Also, what is the error you get ?

Comment: @karthirk yes i think it should be id=pku

Comment: @karthikr Yes, I'm using a custom user and it's imported in my views.py file. The error I have is 'undefined name "pku" '

Comment: Look at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/#adding-extra-context You might have to override `get_context_data` to get the the variable name in the class

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna look at it ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, If you want to use class based views, you should read some more about them. They are thoroughly explained on [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/) and you can read about the specific generics of the framework you're using on the [REST framework docs](http://django-rest-framework.org/) too. I'm not saying that you haven't read those, just that you seem to be missing some basic concepts that are explained there.

Now, to the problem at hand, if you look at the [doc's of the generic view you're extending](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html#retrieveupdatedestroyapiview), you can see that **it represents the endpoints for a single instance**, meaning that it won't act on all your model's instances (as you seem to assume).

Also, you can see that this view is built on top of a series of other classes, the more critical one being [`GenericAPIView`](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views.html#genericapiview). On there you can see two things:

- The `queryset` class field in this context is meant for *filtering the posible instances you can manipulate*, not obtaining the specific instance described on your url.
- The `lookup_field` is the field that defines *which attribute from your model will be used for getting the actual instance*. You should define this field to whatever field you're going to use on your url to identify your object (generally it's pk). It's also important to note that the url should include a keyword argument corresponding to this value.

Internally, the view will take care of calling the `get_object` method, which usese the `lookup_field` value to find the specific model, and then feed that object to the serializer and return the result back to the client.

**DISCLAIMER:** I've never used Django REST framework, I put this answer togheter by reading the relevants docs and based on my experience.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this:
[Resolve function (django 1.4)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.resolve)

Then in your view class method you can do:

```
temp1, args, kwargs = resolve(self.request.path)
```